# Python видит значение SQLite date как integer

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Я создал таблицу с данными клиентов провайдера, чтобы отправлять уведомление на телефон за день до окончания действия тарифа. В таблице SQLite тип данных для даты списания date. При выборе значений открывается календарь и я свободно могу выбрать дату, но после внесения изменений в таблицу значения даты преобразовывается в строку из чисел.
В программе на Python я присваиваю переменным и сравниваю каждую часть даты (день, месяц, год), чтобы узнать срок окончания действия тарифа и сформировать сообщение для клиента. Но Python распознает числа из таблицы как integer. Не понимаю в чем моя ошибка.

[image: Код программы Python]

[image: Таблица SQLite]

Comment: Гугл: ```unixtime, в дату```.... profit :) и правила этого сайта перечитать на тему картинок в вопросах

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, я не знал как по другому лучше показать ошибку

Comment: Помимо показать ошибку у вас так же код в виде картинки, картинки в вопросах допустимы, но только как дополнение, вся та же информация (ваш код\ текст ошибок\ входные данные\ вывод скрипта\....) - должна дублироваться текстом :) ответ на вопрос "что это за формат даты" в первом комментарии, с ним не сложно работать :)

Comment: Скопировать текст ошибки, как текст :) Что касается самой проблемы: sqlite так устроен, что типы колонок не имеют большого значения, это что-то вроде подсказки. Важно, какие данные туда записаны. Тут об этом подробно https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, не могли бы еще подсказать как правильнее указать путь к базе данных? Я хочу, чтобы я мог взять папку с приложением и бд и показать учителю. Приложение и папка с базой данных находятся в одной папке Admin, но если я указываю короткий путь, то python не может найти таблицу Клиенты

Comment: Вероятно, ошибка в нежелании читать документацию :) В "голом" SQLite НЕТ типа даты, но он легко достраивается в питоне, посмотрите пример в родной документации https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#default-adapters-and-converters

Comment: Лучше даже вот тут: [Datatypes In SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), пункт 2.2.